# Finite generation of kernel of derivations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, invariant-theory

Let $A$ be a finitely generated regular $k$-algebra, $k$ algebraically closed of characteristic zero, elements $x_1,\dots,x_n\in A$, such that $dx_1,\dots,dx_n$ give rise to a trivialization of the cotangent bundle (which I think is called being a regular system of parameters).

Then the derivations $\partial_{x_1},\dots,\partial_{x_n}$ are a trivialization of the tangent bundle.  My question is: suppose we take the subalgebra defined to be the kernel of the first $m$ of these, $\partial_{x_1},\dots,\partial_{x_m}$.  Is this subalgebra finitely generated?  If not, or if the question is difficult, are there nice sufficient conditions guaranteeing finite generation?

Note: I am aware that in general kernels of derivations need not be finitely generated, and of course there is the connection to Hilbert's 14th problem, and so general conditions (outside of integrating to a reductive group action, say) are difficult to come by.

EDIT: As I'm getting no responses, I will state the problem slightly differently:

If we choose a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$, and complete at it, we get the power series ring $k[[ x_1,\dots,x_n]]$.  Then $A$ embeds into this power series ring naturally, and our derivations extend to the natural derivations on $k[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$, and so their collective kernel is $k[[x_{m+1},\dots,x_{n}]]$.  Therefore the question can be restated as asking whether $A\cap k[[x_{m+1},\dots,x_n]]$ is finitely generated.

Thank you for any thoughts/ideas/references you may have!

Comment: Just because $x_i$s form a system of parameters, why should it give a trivialization of the cotangent bundle? For example, if $A$ is the polynomial ring in the variables $x_i$, $x_1^2, x_2,\ldots, x_n$ is also a system of parameters but they do not trivialize the cotangent bundle.

Comment: Sorry it should be a regular system of parameters, I think. Really the condition I want is that they trivialize the cotangent bundle so that we have these canonical derivations trivializing the tangent bundle from them.  I'll just write that instead!  Thanks